# what is the best way to implement interactive book in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I can upload  large document as  pdf file into web page no problem. but i want to use arrows to  navigate the book pages   not to upload the whole book at once as this may take long.
can any one help how to do this in mvc app  with or without database? if database is necessary would Mongodb be a better choice? i do not want people to download the book; they can  just read it online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you cannot prevent people to download your content if you visually display it BUT you can discourage them by making it difficult to do so.

That being said you wouldn't have a need a database to do what you want to do. You can but it's not necessary. You can simply find some library online that handle PDF such as iTextSharp cut the book in 1 PDF per page with it when it get uploaded so you have bunch of small files.

Then the trick is simple you query the PDF library to load the file Page1.PDF (arbitrary name) extract text format and output as text nicely has HTML. when the person click the link Page 2 then reload the page with the new PDF to use for display.

Doing so prevent the user from seeing or having access to the PDF file itself and if he want to download it all he will have to copy paste every single page manually or by code if he's a dev. Most common user wont go around copy pasting manually 300 pages because of laziness.

What i would personally do is each file uploaded i would create a folder with the name of the book and call the files 1.pdf, 2.pdf .... per page. Like that if i query the listing of directories i get the list of all books, and if i check the count of files in it i know the total page number. That would allow me to run all that without database.

Comment: thanks Frank; your idea gives me great control  but for a book with 500 pages I need 500 individual pdf files! is this doable? what is the easiest fastest way to get these 500 files; is it possible to program scanner to do this? do you know Kinko's can do this?

Comment: Library such as iTextSharp load a full PDF and then you can simply call something like `Library.PdfObject.Page[10].Save("11.PDF");` you can even Merge PDF files together

Comment: yes i can page through the book which i have saved in a folder. the page number can be set in url ; but how to achieve this with forward and backward arrow on the page?

Comment: those would bet images link with click event and code behind would re-query page with new parameter either `page--` or `page++`